# Firefox extension to open link in Chrome

Tags: firefox, chrome

I am looking for simple solution to add `Open in Chrome` to Firefox menu, similar to the, already existing, open in new window. I am using Firefox 68.4 on Debian Buster.

I found some extensions in the official Firefox store:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome-1/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome-browser/

but these don't work, I get this error:

```
An error has occured! please make sure native-client patch is installed on your machine
```

I don't understand why I need to install some node.js monstrosity from github. The zip file for linux is 20 MB, and i am not even sure what the install.sh script does.

This does not look right. Why should all this be necessary for the trivial task of opening link in another browser. This looks to me like something is extremely badly designed, either on the browser side, or on the extension.

Why is it so complicated to add "open in chrome" in the right-click menu in firefox?

Is there any easier way to do it than described above ?

Comment: The complication is in how Firefox relays the message to Chrome. Although there are many methods of interprocess communication in Linux, browsers do not expose these methods to add-ons for security reasons. The workaround is to install a special type of add-on (native client) in Chrome which is permitted to receive communications from other OS processes.

Comment: And all the other ones seem to be from this person/group, also. I can set up a whole Linux system with 20MB. This is some sort of scam. Consider reporting it. Anyway, didn't find anything working either.

Comment: @WGRM: Hold your horses.  You should know it's *really* NOT nice to call
other people's work provided for you for free "scam" especially if
you don't know how to use it. IIUC, you have to download linux.zip
from [Github project
site](https://github.com/alexmarcoo/open-in-native-client/releases) to
make this addon work. It's 20 MB in size but only because it contains
a pre-compiled `node` binary for 32- and 64-bit systems.  `node` is
[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) package installer and you most
probably can install it on your own using your distro's package
manager...

Comment: ....  After removing `node` binary and re-creating zip archive its
size is only 5.8K.

Comment: Have you tried [Open With](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) add-on?

Answer (score -7):

Firefox is a free software you are free to modify.
the most easy way to achieve what you want is creating your version of Firefox with this option on right click.

There is so many explanations of the reason why to do that is so hard yet in 2020 year, but the money and the right of use is the most reasonable.

Is sad that the capitalism make with us, but is nice what they make with the world =D

accept  the rules of the game and be the best. In this game, the browser war, there is no way (today) of Firefox open easily a link on chrome or another web browser. but you can modify this. edit Firefox source code. take the control!